# How long can a Dove of Planet stay on orbit?

Tags: satellite, planet

I would like to know how many Doves are in operation right now? Also, are there some satellites in standby process or fitting to the orbit?

This question is because some customers ask me how many Doves are operative since the last launch on July  7? How long can the satellite stay online before needing maintenance or relocation or just replacement in the constellation?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Unfortunately, a question like this can only have an accurate answer for a short period of time, and it breaks our "Focused question / Best Answer" model by asking multiple questions.

Comment: I suggest you ask planet https://www.planet.com/contact/ the figure that I heard is that the doves are intended to orbit for 5 years in a decaying fashion... which sounds quite reasonable to me, after 5 years the sensor would be so far behind current technology as to make the captured products useless. The doves are intended to burn up after their intended lifespan, which could be quite spectacular if they re-enter over a night sky.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will ask to planet.com/contact. Sorry to breaks the "Focused question / Best Answer" model" : (

Answer (score 1):

From [Planet Spacecraft Docs](https://www.planet.com/docs/spec-sheets/spacecraft-ops/), it appears a sun-synchronous Dove lasts about 2-3 years in orbit. Planet regularly launches new satellites to replenish the constellation. [Gunter's Space Page](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/flock-1.htm) has a nice description of these satellites as well.